# Limit subscription concurrency in Reactor

Tags: java, cassandra, project-reactor, reactive-streams

I have an utility class centralizing Reactor's `Publisher`s to deal with Cassandra queries:

```
public Mono<ResultSet> execute(Statement statement) {
    return Mono.defer(() -> Mono.fromFuture(FutureConverter
            .toCompletableFuture(session.executeAsync(statement)))
            .publishOn(Schedulers.elastic()));
}
```

It works well expect it does not deal with back-pressure, which ends up with Cassandra pool exhaustion, consequently an error.
Is there a way to to limit the concurrency of the subscriptions (putting them in a FIFO queue) to a given number (which will be match to the pool's size)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not use native reactive support in Java driver 4.5? https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.5/manual/core/reactive/

Comment: also, that version has built-in throttling that you can use

Comment: We may move to it in six months, because we have a lot of version-dependant code, but, in the mean time, we have really important production issues.

Comment: You've already ensured that the wrapped `Future` is lazily created upon request, by using `Mono.defer`. Backpressure cannot really help here, because it is only applied on elements of a single `Flux` or `Mono`. So I guess it all depends on what calls `execute` ?

Comment: There is no way to ensure that no more than X subscription are currently running?

Comment: Using flatMap, you can control the concurrency.

Comment: For a given `Publisher`, here I have a set of `Publisher` and I want to be sure that the number of active `Subscription` does not exceed a given number, the other being queued.